# <img> vs <image> tag in HTML

Tags: html

I am writing an introductory HTML course. I remember discovering 9 years ago as I was learning HTML that both `<img>` and `<image>` worked as the tag for displaying images, at least in IE. Indeed, `<image>` still works in the latest versions of the 5 top browsers.

I realize that `<image>` is incorrect and will not validate with http://validator.w3.org. However, is anyone aware of a browser that will not display an image if `<image>` is used instead of `<img>`?

Furthermore, I assume the modern browsers display images created with the `<image>` tag simply because it is a common mistake that beginners make. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Not because it's a "beginners mistake", but because "broken sites use it, and modern browsers need to help those sites limp along" .. since you're teaching a course you can ensure less broken sites are written: *only* `img` is valid/correct/acceptable. :)

Comment: I have noticed a number of beginners mistakenly use image instead of img in my interactive course (http://codeavengers.com) even though I explicitly state that they need to be careful to use img and NOT image. A number of users had written to me confused about the error message that said they should use img and NOT image because image is INVALID... even though image seems to display perfectly!

Comment: Just require 100% w3c validation *or* a justification for [in]validity on all assignments -- so if they *can* justify `image`, but if they can't .. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes and no. As you point out `<image>` has been a synonym for `<img>` for a long time. I believe it was an early Netscape browser that first did this, possibly to compensate for user error, or possibly because there was dispute at the time whether the element should actually be called `<image>` or `<img>`.

Anyway, as pst points out, once it was implemented in a browser that dominated the market of the time, web pages came to rely on it. Its persistence is then down to commercial pressure on the browser manufacturers. If all the major browsers support it, then Browser A decides that although it supported it in Version V, it won't support it in version V+1, as soon as version V+1 is released, they get lots of messages saying "Site S is broken in your latest browser. You browser is rubbish. I'm going to switch to browser B".

The HTML5 parsing spec requires that the `<image>` tag is mapped to the `img` element at the tree construction stage, so there can never be any justification for using it.

I would be less concerned about browsers, than other HTML consumers, such as the lesser known search engines. I believe that the `image` for `img` synonym is not widely known, and the many such tools would therefore fail to pick up `<image>` as referencing an image resource.

Comment: I had not noticed that the HTML5 parsing spec requires that the image tag is mapped to img. I'm glad you mentioned it as I was assuming in one of my lessons on http://codeavengers.com that the image tag would appear in the DOM tree if the learner made that mistake.

Comment: "I would be less concerned about browsers, than other HTML consumers" good point, persuades me decisively.

Comment: Note that while image is a synonym of img, it's only because it was translated to the DOM as img. CSS on "image", e.g. image.blah { border: 1px solid red } will not work for either img or image, but img.blah {border: 1px solid red } will work for both (in every case that I have seen).

Answer (score 14):

They have different usages in SVGs.  The `image` tag creates a specific [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) in an SVG and can not be replaced by the `img` tag.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jgrumpers/5tc597nw/)

Comment: Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-SVG-19991203/struct.html#ImageElement - very confusing when using canvas -  `.drawImage()` accepts: `CSSImageValue`, `HTMLImageElement`, **`SVGImageElement`**, `HTMLVideoElement`, `HTMLCanvasElement`, `ImageBitmap`, `OffscreenCanvas`, **however `SVGImageElement` IS NOT `<svg>` ELEMENT!** - `<svg>` is actually `SVGSVGElement`

Answer (score 6):

I just finished debugging this problem, which I was committing, having not previously read the above answers.

While not full-blown browsers, an email client is often used as if it were a browser.

I discovered, the hard way, that the Android Gmail client, using naked HTML (with a default naked DTD specification), does exhibit this problem.  It only responds to `<img />` [i.e., not `<image />`].  gmail.com is fine with `<image />`, but not the Android gmail client.

While an email client isn't really a browser, I thought you might be interested anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed the formatting of your post so the HTML shows up. For future reference, blocks of code can be formatted by indenting them with four spaces, inline code can be formatted by surrounding it with backticks (`). You can also select your code and click the **{ }** button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Modern browsers will display code that is not valid in order to make sure that old websites still display correctly and slightly-invalid code doesn't screw up a page.

For example, forgetting to close a `<tr>` before you open a new one - all modern browsers will simply assume you closed it.

I'm not aware of a well-used, up-to-date browser that will fail to display an `<image>` tag, but will display an `<img>` tag.

Comment: According to [whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission) `</tr>` is optional. If you omit `</tr>` tags, your page will still validate. So I am not sure that the `<tr>` example is the best example for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Image is used by the DOM and is why it maps to the img tag in the html. Notice when you use background-image in css or drawImage in javascript, it is fully typed out.

Img is identified as an html tag referencing an image. A side note is that you can now use the `<picture>` tag besides `<img>` tag in the html.

The `<picture>` tag in HTML5 has/uses the properties that `<audio>` && `<video>` tags have. It helps remove issues with mobile device sizes and todays hi-res images.

What works well on desktop still renders properly when applied to a phone or table size screen.

See ~://[quick over-view of picture vs. img](https://blog.bitsrc.io/why-you-should-use-picture-tag-instead-of-img-tag-b9841e86bf8b)