# What is the difference between <img> tag and new Image().src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any specific reason we use `new Image().src=URL` instead of `<img> URL </img>`. I see this kind of usage mostly in web tracking  or some image pixels etc. would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to [so] - I hope you'll enjoy contributing to [so]! Sorry, but I'm not sure what is the actual codes that you're comparing - could you explain a bit further? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to compare `new Image` with `document.createElement('img')`, perhaps?

Comment: As Qantas already said, I am also confused, I think you are comparing code snippets of two different languages, please make your question more clear to get the help quickly. Anyways you can follow some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928566/img-vs-image-tag-in-html)

Comment: `<img> URL </img>` is invalid. `<img src="URL" />`

Comment: we can include the images using <img> tags.but why do we need objects to create images. like new Image().src="image url". Are there any advantages? In my case,I implemented some analytics code in my website using tag management system. The actual code is <img height="1" width="1" "  src="//www.domainname.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxx/?value=1000&amp;label=xyz&amp;&amp;script=0"/> but why should we use the same pixel in new Image().src="www.domainname.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxx/?value=1000&amp;label=xyz&amp;&amp;script=0" in this format. is there any advantage of using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DOM nodes mainly in two ways:

- You put them in the HTML using tags like `<img src="foo.jpg">`
- You create them dynamically from Javascript using for example `document.createElement`

If the nodes are fixed then static creation is better because allows a designer to create and edit a page directly without having to know Javascript. If however they're created dynamically depending on the user actions on the page then you cannot place them in the HTML and you're forced to use Javascript.

Somethings you may need to just act on an existing DOM element and you may see code like

```
<img id="pic" src="foo.jpg">
```

in the HTML (note the `id=` part)

and then you can access it from code using for example

```
document.getElementById("pic").src = "bar.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `img` tag has an attribute called `src`. The HTML in your second example is invalid.