# html tag <img> and <image>

Tags: html, image, tags

I have one little question. I code the web page and use the `<image>` tag. The web page is tuned in Edge browser and everything is OK. The browser recognizes that I want to use the image and apply CSS properties. But when I open Chrome or Opera, the images will appear but the browser can not apply CSS properties. Why are not my browsers able to apply CSS properties? When I change the `<image>` tag to `<img>`, it's all right.

Comment: "but the browser can not apply CSS properties" - how have you specified these properties? On the 'image' tag, or based on a class or ID without the actual tag name?

Comment: Vaguely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928566/img-vs-image-tag-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image):

> The obsolete HTML Image element (`<image>`) is an obsolete remnant of an ancient version of HTML lost in the mists of time; use the standard `<img>` element instead. Seriously, the specification even literally uses the words "Don't ask" when describing this element.

Comment: In fact, `<image>` has never been part of any standard HTML specification ever.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with the `<img>` tag and it should work.

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain why the browser isn't applying the alias for CSS too.

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.