# Image not rendering from Props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a component that gets Props from the parent, the props has a field for image address, which I am trying to display. The below is what I have written:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface Props {
    src: string;
}

class ProductImage extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div><Image className="img-fluid p-2 border" src={this.props.src}></Image><p>{this.props.src}</p></div>;
    }
}

export default ProductImage;
```

I can confirm that in the

tag above the props is correctly bought to the child and is valid.
Somehow not able to display the address.

Edit: This is my working directory:

```
public/
    images/
        img1.jpg
        img2.jpg
    index.html
src/
    assets/
        images/
            img1.jpg
            img2.jpg
    components/
        product/
            Product.tsx
            ProductImage.tsx <-- Using the code here
```

Edit2:
I have tried following these:

```
 - src={require('../../assets/images/'+this.props.src+'.jpg')} //props just has image name here
 - src={require('src/assets/images/+this.props.src+'.jpg')} 
 - src={require('/images/+this.props.src+'.jpg')} // Copied image folder to public
```

Comment: Use <img /> tag instead of <image></image> Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928566/img-vs-image-tag-in-html

Comment: He has imported `Image` from `react-bootstrap` module.

Comment: Have you logged the `src` prop in console? What does it show?

Comment: As you can see from the code, I am displaying it is a <p> tag. And it is showing: src/assests/images/img1.png as expected the image path

Comment: @AshishDeora, I tried <img> too and even that is not rendering the image

Comment: Are you getting the image tag in the dom? Can you inspect the Dom and confirm? I mean, is the tag rendering without the image? Just wanted to check that.

Comment: Images are standalone tag in React-Bootstrap - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/images/

Comment: please tell what error is coming?

Comment: @RAHULFAUJDAR, there is no error, but the Image itself is not getting displayed. The props is passed correctly, it has the path of the image correctly, yet the image is not getting rendered.

Comment: @SharathKamlekar, Yes You have not given width and height with the image.  <Image className="img-fluid p-2 border" style={{width:"100%",height:"600px"}} src={this.props.src}></Image>

Comment: No this doesn't help, I am getting an empty frame with no image in it.
My actual question here is image not getting rendered based on passed props even though it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try directly specify the image path using require('../pathToImh/img') in  element like this

```
class ProductImage extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div>
           <img className="img-fluid p-2 border" src={require(this.props.src)} />
           <p>{this.props.src}</p>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'src/assets/images/img1.jpg'

Comment: try adding "./" before the path

Comment: No, it is not in the same directory so to use ./

Comment: Try to give a global path of any image from Google in src and check if its working. If yes, then there is some issue with the path of your image. To fix, you can check the relative path of the image from the file where u have written ur <img /> or else simply try experimenting different values before ur path like "./", "../", "../imagePath/.."

Comment: Yes for some random image it is rendering. So we can say that it is just matter of path. See my edit to know what all I have tried.

Comment: try `src={require('../../../assets/images/'+this.props.src+'.jpg')}`

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, You have not given width and height with the image.*

*please try this:-*

***DEMO:-***

```
class ProductImage extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div><Image className="img-fluid p-2 border" style={{width:"100%", height:"600px"}} src={this.props.src}></Image><p>{this.props.src}</p></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an issue with size, as the image is pre-applied with size.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the path. When you put in the src attribute `/src/assets/images/img1.jpg`, React tries to get that path inside the `public` folder. Try change the image file to a folder named `images` inside public folder and use `/images/img1.jpg` in src attribute.

Comment: I have tried this too, copied folder from assets to public folder and tried to use like this:
src={require(this.props.src)} but seems like it is not determining that too

Comment: Instead of `src={require(this.props.src)}` use `src={this.props.src}`

Comment: In my solution, you must ensure the passed value is `/images/img1.jpg` and the image is placed where I said.

Answer (score 0):

I had to define the image like this in my DummyFile.tsx:

```
import img1 from 'src/assets/images/img1.jpg';
import img2 from 'src/assets/images/img2.jpg';
export const dummyProducts = [
{
          id: 1,
          name: "Product 1",
          price: 149,
          photo: img1,
          details: "Lorem ipsum"
     },
     {
          id: 2,
          name: "Product 2",
          price: 9,
          photo: img1,
          details: "Lorem ipsum"
     }
];
```

Previously I was passing `photo: 'src/assets/images/img2.jpg'`. Then I used in the image like this:

```
<Image className="img-fluid p-2 border" src={this.props.src}></Image>;
```

This helped me render in my case.