# Images aren't rendering when Blazor variable bound to style in <image> tag

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm playing around with a basic Dot-Net web assembly application. In the application I'm displaying two images using two different image tags `image` and `img`. The size of the image is bound to a private variable `Size`. I've noticed a problem where images do not render in a specific scenario using the `image` tag.

##### Replication:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm
```

I downloaded the SVG from: [Bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/search/), then I placed the SVG file in `"wwwroot/Media/"`.

###### In `index.razor` I've updated the code as follows:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<img src="Media/search.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="@Size" height="@Size">
<image src="Media/search.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="@Size" height="@Size"/>

@code
{
    private static string Size => "75";
}
```

The result of running the above code shows only one image displaying

[image: The resulting image]

Through process of elimination, the image defined using the `image` tag is the problem here. If you tweak the code to use hardcoded values i.e.

```
<image src="Media/search.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="75" height="75"/>
```

then the code works again as expected.

[image]

I'm aware that `<image>` is deprecated, but I'd like to understand if the reason the binding breaks the image displaying is due to the deprecation or something else?

**Update**

The generated HTML using the template is

```
<!--!--><div class="top-row px-4" b-vv8m6rf2se=""><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank" b-vv8m6rf2se="">About</a></div>

        <article class="content px-4" b-vv8m6rf2se=""><!--!--><!--!--><!--!--><!--!-->

<!--!--><h1 tabindex="-1">Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<img src="Media/search.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="75" height="75">
<image src="Media/search.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="75" height="75"></image></article>
```

Comment: What html is generated from that template?

Comment: I've add the output to the bottom of the post for you @zerkms :)

Comment: So `image` element is there exactly as you expect it right?

Comment: If `<img>` works, then use it.  Blazor doesn't really have anything to do with what is displayed-- its job is to send the markup to the client, and cleverly adjust it as needed.  Much more interestingly IMO-- if you have a small-kb icon that you don't think needs to be cached, you might want to consider using inline `<svg>` tags instead of an image-- then you can parameterize colors, line thickness, and animations.  You can even add `@onclick` Handlers or any other event you'd use in Blazor.  Open any .svg file in notepad to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @zerkms indeed it's where I expect it to be. Comparing the hardcoded img size HTML to the original - it seems like the `image` tag is automagically converted to `img`. Could be that the display for `image` tags is deprecated and blazor is doing it's best to try convert it for me.

Comment: When you use legacy markup like that, it's up to the browser what it wants to do with it.  The obvious question is-- why do you want to use legacy markup?

Comment: <image in html: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image#browser_compatibility

<image in svg : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting find, although of course not of any practical value, just use `<img>`.
I could easily reproduce this with a jpg image so it's not about svg.

Now for a speculative answer:

Blazor treats `<image>` like any other tag and the generated HTML looks like expected. But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929639/60761),

> The HTML5 parsing spec requires that the  tag is mapped to the img element at the tree construction stage

This makes me think that when the complete tag is rendered just once it works fine, handling is up to the browser.

But after Blazor has filled in the `@Size` it will try to update the HTML it generated earlier. If the Browser really changed `<image>` to `<img>` internally then the JS Bridge will have trouble finding the element again and the updates fail.